# How can I reverse USDZ animation in realityKit

Tags: animation, swiftui, realitykit, visionos

How can i play a USDZ entity animation in reverse?
I have tried to put a negative value to the speed as I was doing in SceneKit to make the animation reverse play but it did not work.
here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ImmersiveView: View {
    @State var entity = Entity()
    @State var openDoor: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            if let mainDoor = try? await Entity(named: "Door.usdz") {
                
                if let frame = mainDoor.findEntity(named: "DoorFrame")
                {

                    frame.position = [0, 0, -8]

                    frame.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: (270 * (.pi / 180)), axis: SIMD3(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
                    
                    content.add(frame)
                    
                    entity = frame.findEntity(named: "Door")!
                    
                    entity.components.set(InputTargetComponent(allowedInputTypes: .indirect))
                    
                    entity.components.set(HoverEffectComponent())
                    
                    let entityModel = entity.children[0]
                    
                    entityModel.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                }
            }
        }
        .gesture(
            SpatialTapGesture()
                .targetedToEntity(entity)
                .onEnded { value in
                    print(value)
                    if openDoor == true
                    {
                        let animController = entity.playAnimation(entity.availableAnimations[0], transitionDuration: 0 , startsPaused: true)

                        animController.speed = 1.0
                        animController.resume()
                        
                        openDoor = false
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let animController = entity.playAnimation(entity.availableAnimations[0], transitionDuration: 0 , startsPaused: true)
                        
                        animController.speed = -1.0 // it does not work to reverse
                        animController.resume()
                        
                        openDoor = true
                    }
                }
            )
    }
}
```

The Door Should Be Opened with first click which is already happening and closed on second click which not happening as it does not reverse play the animation

[image]

Also here is a link for my door USDZ if you wanna try
[enter link description here](https://www.worldhotelity.com/stack/Door.usdz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting Apple Support about this issue they have responded with the correct way to reverse animation for visionOS, rather it is the correct way to add many other adjustments for the animation play like repeat and start and end time so it did help a lot, now here is the working code

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ImmersiveView: View {
    @State var entity = Entity()
    @State var openDoor: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            if let mainDoor = try? await Entity(named: "Door.usdz") {
                
                if let frame = mainDoor.findEntity(named: "DoorFrame")
                {

                    frame.position = [0, 0, -8]

                    frame.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: (270 * (.pi / 180)), axis: SIMD3(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
                    
                    content.add(frame)
                    
                    entity = frame.findEntity(named: "Door")!
                    
                    entity.components.set(InputTargetComponent(allowedInputTypes: .indirect))
                    
                    entity.components.set(HoverEffectComponent())
                    
                    let entityModel = entity.children[0]
                    
                    entityModel.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                }
            }
        }
        
        .gesture(
            SpatialTapGesture()
                .targetedToEntity(entity)
                .onEnded { value in
                    print(value)
                    if openDoor == true
                    {
                        var playerDefinition = entity.availableAnimations[0].definition
                        playerDefinition.speed = 1
                        playerDefinition.repeatMode = .none
                        playerDefinition.trimDuration = 0
                        
                        let playerAnimation = try! AnimationResource.generate(with: playerDefinition)

                        entity.playAnimation(playerAnimation)

                        openDoor = false
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var playerDefinition = entity.availableAnimations[0].definition
                        playerDefinition.speed = -1
                        playerDefinition.repeatMode = .none
                        playerDefinition.trimDuration = 0
                        
                        let playerAnimation = try! AnimationResource.generate(with: playerDefinition)

                        entity.playAnimation(playerAnimation)
                        
                        openDoor = true
                    }
                }
            )
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In visionOS 1.1, the `AnimationPlaybackController` object is still not able to play back a reverse asset animation, as it was in [iOS RealityKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72513552/slow-down-the-arsession-without-slowing-down-the-camera-feed/72514547#72514547). For now, I recommend using authoring tool like Autodesk Maya to create a reverse animation of your USDZ model.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var controller: AnimationPlaybackController? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            if let sktr = try? await Entity(named: "Skater.usdz") {
                sktr.position.z = -3
                
                let resource = sktr.availableAnimations[0].repeat(count: 5)
                controller = sktr.playAnimation(resource)

                controller?.speed = -1.0         // not working in visionOS
                content.add(sktr)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Andy Jazz , in fact I was expecting this answer cause I really searched everywhere for it, and it is unfortunate that apple has not make this simple and rather essential API which would help me a lot, Still making an external animation played in reverse for all my project is too complicated not in implementation but for the size of my full USDZ which contains almost 1200 animations as it was migrated from a scene game, but if there is no way I will start doing so, hopefully the memory of the VisionPro would stand this, Thanx again, and hopefully another solution appear in the future

Comment: @Ostoura, I really hope that Apple will bring back this functionality for asset animation in the near future.

Comment: Me Too, meanwhile I will try to raise an issue to apple, hopefully they would respond and save me from a lot of work on my 3d model.

Comment: Thanx @ Andy Jazz, After contacting Apple Support they gave me a solution for the proper way to reverse Animation and many other tweaks for the animation, and it do work on visionOS 1.0

Comment: @Ostoura, great job. The upvote from me.